# How to embed a website in an application?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am developing android app. In that I need to open the website within the app. No request of pre-installed browsers on my mobile.

```
if (filename == 'governmentBuildingDetails.html'){
    var gbdName;
    var gbdnormalWorkingHours;
    var gbdramadanWorkingHours;
    var gbdwebsiteAddress;
    var gbdphoneNumber;
    var gbdpoAddress;
    var gbdemailAddress;
    var gbdtwitterLink;
    $.ajax({
           //url:ipAddress+"/api/content/render/false/query/+structureName:GovernmentDepartmentUaq%20+(conhost:48190c8c-42c4-46af-8d1a-0cd5db894797%20conhost:SYSTEM_HOST)%20+languageId:1*%20+deleted:false%20%20+working:true/orderby/modDate%20desc/limit/999",
           url:"../json/governmentBuildings.json",
            dataType:"json",

            success:function(data){
                //$.mobile.loading("hide");
                function getQueryVariable(variable)
                {
                       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                       var vars = query.split("&");
                       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
                       }
                       return(false);
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                  var deptName= getQueryVariable('name');
                  console.log(deptName);
                  var space='%20';
                  console.log(deptName.replace(/%20/gi,' '));
                 var gov_dept_name = deptName.replace(/%20/gi,' ');
                 var valGovDetails=data.contentlets;
                for(var i=0;i<valGovDetails.length;i++)
                { 
                    /*console.log('in each');
                    console.log('gov dept'+ gov_dept_name+' name '+val.name);
                    console.log(typeof gov_dept_name);
                    console.log(typeof val.name);*/
                    if(valGovDetails[i].name === gov_dept_name){

                        gbdName = valGovDetails[i].name;
                        gbdnormalWorkingHours = valGovDetails[i].normalWorkingHours;
                        gbdramadanWorkingHours = valGovDetails[i].ramadanWorkingHours;
                        gbdwebsiteAddress = valGovDetails[i].websiteAddress;
                        gbdphoneNumber = valGovDetails[i].phoneNumber;
                        gbdpoAddress = valGovDetails[i].poAddress;
                        gbdemailAddress = valGovDetails[i].emailAddress;
                        gbdtwitterLink = valGovDetails[i].twitterLink;
                        gbdText = gbdName + gbdnormalWorkingHours + gbdramadanWorkingHours + gbdwebsiteAddress + gbdphoneNumber + gbdpoAddress + gbdemailAddress + gbdtwitterLink;
                        $('#dept_name').empty().append(valGovDetails[i].name);
                        $('#dept_details_content').empty().append('<br/>'+'<div class="shareMe"><div class="dept_details_content_right shareMe">Working Hours:</div>'+'<div class="dept_details_content_right">'+valGovDetails[i].normalWorkingHours+'</div><br/>'+
                        '<div class="dept_details_content_right shareMe">Ramadan:</div>'+'<div class="dept_details_content_right">'+valGovDetails[i].ramadanWorkingHours+'</div>'+
                        '<p><a class="website" data-transition="slide" href="'+valGovDetails[i].websiteAddress+'"><img src="../images/government_buildings/globe-icon.svg" alt="globe">'+valGovDetails[i].websiteAddress+'</a></p>'+
                        '<h4 class="dept_details_content_right heading">Contact Us:</h4>'+
                        '<p><a data-transition="slide" href="tel:'+valGovDetails[i].phoneNumber+'" class="telMe"><img  src="../images/government_buildings/phone.svg" alt="phone">'+valGovDetails[i].phoneNumber+'</a></p>'+
                        '<p class="shareMe"><img src="../images/government_buildings/fax-en.svg" alt="fax">'+valGovDetails[i].faxNumber+'</p>'+
                        '<p><img src="../images/government_buildings/post-box.svg" alt="address" class="gov_building_poBox shareMe">'+valGovDetails[i].poAddress+'</p>'+
                        '<p><a data-transition="slide" href="mailto:'+valGovDetails[i].emailAddress+'" class="shareMe"><img src="../images/government_buildings/mail.svg" alt="email">'+valGovDetails[i].emailAddress+'</a></p>'+
                        '<p ><a class="shareMe" data-transition="slide" href="'+valGovDetails[i].facebookLink+'"><img src="../images/government_buildings/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">'+valGovDetails[i].facebookLink+'</a></p>'+
                        '<p><a data-transition="slide" href="'+valGovDetails[i].twitterLink+'" class="shareMe"><img src="../images/government_buildings/twitter.svg" alt="twitter">'+valGovDetails[i].twitterLink+'</a></p>'+
                        '<div id="gov_features" style="float:right;"><a data-transition="slide" href="directions.html?lat='+valGovDetails[i].latitude+'&lng='+valGovDetails[i].longitude+'&name='+gov_dept_name+'"><img src="../images/government_buildings/Direction.svg" alt="geolocation" ></a>'+
                        '<a href="#" class="shareWithMe" onclick="return false;" ><img src="../images/government_buildings/Share.svg" alt="Share" ></a></div></div>'

                        );
                    }

                }               

            /*$('.website').on('click',function(e){
                WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView.loadUrl('gbdwebsiteAddress');
                });*/


              $('.shareWithMe').on('click', function(e){


                       // alert($(this).parents('.shareMe').text());
                        //alert($(this).parents('.shareMe').find('.telMe').attr('href')); 
                       /* var locHref = location.href;
                        var emergencyShare1 = $(this).parents('.shareMe').text();
                        var emergencyShare2 = $(this).parents('.shareMe').find('.telMe').attr('href');
                        var emergencyShare = emergencyShare1+' : '+emergencyShare2; */
                       // console.log(a,b,c,d);
                       // alert(d);
                        if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG' && e.target.alt == 'Share'){
                            // alert('Cool');
                            window.plugins.socialsharing.share(gbdText, function(){
                                alert('Working');
                            });                         
                        }


                    }); 

            },
            error:function(e){
                console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        });

}
```

I want my app will request for by poping up the list of pre-installed browsers on my android mobile

Comment: It is very good that you added the source code to your question, without it helping you seems impossible. However, please always strip your code to a minimal example (i.e. so that we can reproduce your problem, we certainly do not need code which is commented out). Also, even more important, it is still unclear what problem you are facing: Do you get any error or an unexpected result? Then please add this to your question.

Comment: Post's been edited. Voting to reopen.